# Show dialog fragment from onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got received a crash for my app from an user with 4.2 (my app supports 3.1+). The crash is due to IllegalStateException calling a `show()` in `onActivityResult()`. The docs says that this method should be called before onResume() but when exactly? It seems to me that it get called before the state restoration. I found this [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17787) report where the last comment says that actually can happen before `onStart()`, `onRestart()` and `onResume()`, can someone help me to understand? I can move the fragment away but if it's true that `onActivityResult()` could be called before `onStart()` I can't use any restored variable inside it because I'm not sure if the restoration happened.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
......
    if (cd == null)
        cd = ConnectingDialog.findOrCreate(getFragmentManager());
    cd.show(getFragmentManager(), ConnectingDialog.TAG);
.......
}
```

Comment: dear please post your code & logcat

Comment: @cerebro I added the code, I haven't got logcat since it's a crash reported by google play. I don't post it just because the code is obfuscated and it shows only the IllegalStateException and the show called